# BigQuery Node API is much slower than the GUI

Tags: google-bigquery

A query run with the Node Api is about 25 times slower than the same query run in the GUI. Am I missing something? I use the `.query()` function in Node. As an example running this query on the GUI takes about 13 secs.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  repository.url,
  repository.has_downloads
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested`
```

This query returns 2.5 million rows. The equivalent Node code takes about 336s and looks like this;

```
const BigQuery = require("@google-cloud/bigquery")

const query = `
SELECT
  repository.url,
  repository.has_downloads
FROM \`bigquery-public-data.samples.github_nested\``

new BigQuery({
  projectId: "project-id",
})
  .query({
    query: query,
    useLegacySql: false,
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Do you have any additional data? Query? Size of the query? Can you try this with a query over public data and share your results with us?

Comment: Might be useful to share you code too ;-)

Comment: Added an example

Comment: I've personally tested it and and I've not seen any difference with the GUI and my VM using almost your very same code. 

What kind of machine are you using to execute the query? is it remote?, bandwidth limited?,  memory limited? , etc?